# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I`ve faced with very strange issue that i`m struggling with it for 2 days. I tried to run code below on few dev machines and it`s running successfully. But when i try to run it on production server with Windows Server 2008 R2 - it failed with message:

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Here is the code example:

```
try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; // ignoring certificate errors
            Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadString("https://smlegacygateway-integration.mysmartmove.com/LandlordApi/v1/ServerTime");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something goes wrong");
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Everything is fine.");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Could you please help me with with any ideas why only on Windows Server 2008 R2 it failed??? I tried to run it on Windows Server 2012 - everything is fine.

P.S. I run this console app with Admin permission, so it should not related to any gap of rights 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know why. I assume it could be because Windows 2012 supports new crypto algorithms that Windows 2008 doesn't.

According to [this ssl test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=smlegacygateway-integration.mysmartmove.com) server supports only TSL 1.2 and TSL 1.1 and only selected few cipher suites. All handshake test that passed were done by using TSL 1.2 so I would go with this protocol in `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`.

The reason why connection failed in Windows 2008 could be found in CAPI2 event log. You must enable it first and then try to connect to the server (`smlegacygateway-integration.mysmartmove.com`) again.
[image: CAPI2 event log]

Oh, final advice. Please don't do this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; // ignoring certificate errors
```

If you have to implement certificate validation then implement it. Returning always true is not a good choice. If you don't need to override it then don't touch it :)